# How to split a column in DataFrame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I imported a dataset looks like this.

```
Peak, Trough
0   1857-06-01, 1858-12-01
1   1860-10-01, 1861-06-01
2   1865-04-01, 1867-12-01
3   1869-06-01, 1870-12-01
4   1873-10-01, 1879-03-01
5   1882-03-01, 1885-05-01
6   1887-03-01, 1888-04-01
```

it is a CSV file. But when I check the `.shape`, it is

```
(7, 1)
```

I thought CSV file can automatically be seperated by its commas, however this one doesn't work.

I want to split this column into two, sperated by comma, and also the column names as well. How can I do that?

Comment: It seems there is no separator `,`, is possible check it in `text editor` ?

Comment: can you please post a snippet of csv (raw text)

Comment: The data is in https://fredhelp.stlouisfed.org/fred/data/understanding-the-data/recession-bars/, I copied them into an excel, then save as CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'sep' tag in read_csv

It's like:

```
df = read_csv(path, sep = ', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Same data to text file or csv and then use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `skipinitialspace=True` and `parse_dates` for convert values to datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=[0,1])
print (df.head())
        Peak     Trough
0 1857-06-01 1858-12-01
1 1860-10-01 1861-06-01
2 1865-04-01 1867-12-01
3 1869-06-01 1870-12-01
4 1873-10-01 1879-03-01

print (df.dtypes)
Peak      datetime64[ns]
Trough    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If data are in excel in one column is possible use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by first column, convert to datetimes and last set new columns names:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(', ', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
df1.columns = df.columns[0].split(', ')
print (df1.head()) 
        Peak     Trough
0 1857-06-01 1858-12-01
1 1860-10-01 1861-06-01
2 1865-04-01 1867-12-01
3 1869-06-01 1870-12-01
4 1873-10-01 1879-03-01

print (df1.dtypes)       
Peak      datetime64[ns]
Trough    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```